# Mogenerator ios

Tags: ios, ios5, mogenerator

I installed Mogenerator. Now what do I do? How do I use it?

The first problem I have is that I have no idea check the chekbox "run scripts only when installing" for mogenerator or not ?

Answer (score 1):

To which checkbox exactly are you referring? One on a "Run Script" build phase within Xcode?

Mogenerator is a tool for generating model classes from your Core Data model. Since it does not yet have an Xcode 4 compatible plugin you want to run it as a command line tool whenever you make changes to your Core Data model.

You could do so in a Run Script build phase. In that case you would probably not want to wait until you are installing the app as you would then not have access to newly added properties on your model classes until you ran an install build. Instead you really want the script to run when you have made any changes to your Core Data model and before you start compiling your project.

I find Core Data changes to be relatively infrequent so I might choose to run mogenerator manually when I make a change rather than rerunning it unnecessarily on every build. I'd probably save my mogenerator command line setting in a shell script or rake task but alternately you might follow John Blanco's example and create a new build target containing only your mogenerator Run Script build phase so you can run it on demand from within Xcode: http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/

Comment: ok thanks , but when I uncheck the  checkbox "run script only when installing"  mogenerator generates models like this `@interface _Contact : AbstractRootManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* *birthDay;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* *contactId;
@end`  and I can't change it. what do you think about this?